# Como melhorar/simplificar essa minha estrutura?

Tags: c#, revisão-de-código

Temos esses vários `ifs` e gostaria de saber se há uma forma de simplificá-los, deixá-los mais objetivos, fáceis de entender, ...

Basicamente, fazemos um `where` de `retorno` para filtrar essa lista.
Nesse `where`, só adicionamos a condição quando o valor da variável for `"S"`.

```cs
var retorno = query.Select(x => x.n).Distinct();

if (fin == "S" && ped == "S" && sol == "S")
{
    retorno = retorno.Where(x => x.fin == "S" || x.ped == "S" || x.sol == "S");
}
else if (fin == "S" && ped == "S" && sol == "N")
{
    retorno = retorno.Where(x => x.fin == "S" || x.ped == "S");
}
else if (fin == "S" && ped == "N" && sol == "S")
{
    retorno = retorno.Where(x => x.fin == "S" || x.sol == "S");
}
else if (fin == "S" && ped == "N" && sol == "N")
{
    retorno = retorno.Where(x => x.fin == "S");
}
else if (fin == "N" && ped == "S" && sol == "S")
{
    retorno = retorno.Where(x => x.ped == "S" || x.sol == "S");
}
else if (fin == "N" && ped == "S" && sol == "N")
{
    retorno = retorno.Where(x => x.ped == "S");
}
else if (fin == "N" && ped == "N" && sol == "S")
{
    retorno = retorno.Where(x => x.sol == "S");
}
```

**EDIT** (ainda não estou satisfeito)

```cs
var listaRetorno = new List<MeuObjeto>();

if (fin == "S")
{
    listaRetorno = AdicionarItensLista(ret.Where(x => x.fin == "S").ToList(), listaRetorno);
}
if (ped == "S")
{
    listaRetorno = AdicionarItensLista(ret.Where(x => x.ped == "S").ToList(), listaRetorno);
}
if (sol == "S")
{
    listaRetorno = AdicionarItensLista(ret.Where(x => x.sol == "S").ToList(), listaRetorno);
}


private List<MeuObjeto> AdicionarItensLista(List<MeuObjeto> lista, List<MeuObjeto> listaAnterior)
{
    foreach (var item in lista)
    {
            listaAnterior.Add(item);
    }

    return listaAnterior;
}
```

Comment: Para usar a [tag:revisao-código] é importante [edit] a postagem e, além de fornecer um código funcional para otimização, explicar exatamente o que o código deve fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomando a frase `Nesse where, só adicionamos a condição quando o valor da variável for "S".` como premissa, pode-se fazer algo como:

```cs
var retorno = query
                .Select(x => x.n)
                .Distinct()
                .Where(x => (fin == "S" && x.fin == fin)
                    || (ped == "S" && x.ped == ped)
                    || (sol == "S" && x.sol == sol));
```

A lógica deste código é que caso o valor do seu filtro seja diferente de "S", ele não será adicionado ao `Where` e serão retornados todos os resultados. Caso ele seja "S", o filtro será adicionado e retornará somente os resultados com "S".